# retrieve image from memory , crop it and save it again in memory

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, canvas

I am using JQuery Imazen.Crop to crop images.

Here are the requirements

- Upload Image
- Store in memory
- Show on canvas
- On Crop buttom click event save the image in memory.

**aspx page**

```
    <asp:Image ID="imgCanvass" CssClass="imageCanvass" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/photos/inspectors/5500-tmp.png" Width="500" Height="500" />
    <ic:CropImage ID="cropImage" runat="server" Image="imgCanvass" CanvasWidth="500"  FixedAspectRatio="true" X="100" Y="100" W="132" H="170" />
```

**Code to store uploaded image in stream and displaying in canvas.**

```
 If filBrowse.HasFile Then
        fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filBrowse.FileName)

        Dim fs As Stream = filBrowse.PostedFile.InputStream
        Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
        Dim bytes As [Byte]() = br.ReadBytes(CInt(fs.Length))
        Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

        imgCanvass.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString("data:image/png;base64,") & base64String   
        Me.panelCanvass.Visible = True
    End If
```

I can use cropImage.Crop command to physically store the image on disk but instead i need to save it in memory so that i can either be save on disk or in database when user click the save button on page.

Can i do anything with crop url values "data:image/png?crop=261,43,461,203&cropxunits=500&cropyunits=400"

Answer (score 0):

You can send those values to [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net), along with the source stream, and have the result written to a MemoryStream.

`new ImageJob(sourceStream,memoryStream, new Instructions("crop=261,43,461,203&cropxunits=500&cropyunits=400")).Build();`